# How to mimick the back button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net webform project. It has an edit form which displays member data retrieved from database in several text and combo boxes. The user can edit any of those items. After edit, when they click the "verify" button, it will take them ro verifyAndSave.aspx page through Server.Transfer method. This new page has two buttons: Save and Cancel. When they click the Cancel button, it should take them back to the earlier page with all the edited data intact. For the cancel button's click event, in the code behind, I am again using Server.transfer. It goes to the earlier page but the problem is that it shouws only the data from the database. Any edits made by the user is gone. However if I use the back button, I see all the edits made by the user. please let me know how to implement the Cancel button correctly.

Thansk

Comment: use javascript `window.history.back()`

Comment: Is there some reason not to do a confirmation dialog (thinking a jquery dialog here) instead of going to another page. This has several advantages: 1> The server doesn't have to serve any extra pages. 2> It looks nicer 3> It can very naturally return to the state you desire if you cancel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET Button code would look like this:

```
<asp:button id="btnCancel" runat="server" text="Cancel" OnClientClick="JavaScript:window.history.back(1); return false;" />
```

If you want to do it from code behind, you can try the following:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "goBack", "history.go(-1);", True)
```

Comment: Hi, trying the above code snippet and getting an error on 'Me' in the snippet (Me.GetType(),... it doesn't exist in the current context. Could someone explain what it is / where it comes from, so I work out what it should reference. many thanks.

Comment: Me.GetType() is VB.NET  try using this.GetType() for C#.

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1);">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have the confirmation functions/markup on the initial page. Then use jQuery to hide/show the two panels dependning on if next or cancel is pressed. That way there are no post backs, and no data will be lost.

```
$('#NextBtn').Click(function(){
     $('#PanelInitial').hide()
     $('#PanelConfirm').show()
});
$('#CanelBtn').Click(function(){
     $('#PanelInitial').show()
     $('#PanelConfirm').hide()
});
```